# Longitudinal data on a prognostic model

Tags: panel-data

I am struggling to analyze longitudinal data on a prognostic model.
I used a multivariate Cox model to select predictors at time1. I also have measures of these predictors at time2 (the event of interest), but only in those observations that had the event (I don't have data at time2 of those observations without the event).

So, I was wondering if I could add more power to my prognostic model but leveraging data of those predictors at time2. However, I am afraid that I cannot as I don't have data on those observations without the event of interest.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the case that you can't conduct a valid analysis incorporating the time2 variables at all. This is due to a number of reasons, most of which you've already identified. But to expand:

1. The point of a risk prediction model is to predict the absolute risk of an event over a given time interval. If a subject's covariates change, the expectation of the provider and patient is that they should just re-enter those covariates into the risk model and obtain updated estimates of risk - note this makes rather strong assumptions about the event process!
2. If a risk model were created with time1 and time2 variables, you would need a contrived way to estimate an individual's risk at both times. In a sense, they enter the risk set at time 1, but you need some form of marginalization or prediction to "fill in" the time2 covariate values, and then you suddenly pivot their risk based on the truth at time 2,
3. You already know there is a dangerous form of bias by measuring covariates only on subjects with events. I don't think we can say anything in general, but you will be hard pressed to present a huge extent of external data to justify that the time2 variables predict disease - and not the other way around - if they are in fact measured post-hoc as you say.